# References regularity of solutions to linear system of first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

Consider a linear  first order PDE:
$$\sum_i A_i(x)\frac \partial{\partial x_i}f(x)  = B(x) f(x)$$
$f:\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ where $\Omega$ is bounded and $A_i,B :\Omega\to Hom(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ are smooth.

> I am looking for references about the regularity of the solutions and in particular to the effect of $B$.

More specifically,  I am interested to the case  where the PDE takes the form
$$\frac \partial {\partial t} f(t,x) + \sum_i A_i(x)\frac\partial{\partial x_i}f(t,x)  = B(x) f(t,x)$$

Is there a systematic treatment for these equations (like Elliptic regularity for elliptic PDEs)?

Suppose that we can prove that if $B= 0$ then the solutions are smooth what happens then when $B\neq 0$?